# Change Panel color with if statement

Tags: c#, css, asp.net

I'm having an issue with changing the background color in aspx
My code

```
`<Div class="panel-<%=i >= 100 ? "Red" c >= 1 ? "Blue" : "green"%> "onclick= window.location = 'xxx.aspx';">`
```

For some reason it goes red when `i` is less them 100 and Green when `i` is greater but when `c` is grater then 1 it doesn't change

The red green and blue is CSS.

Answer (score 0):

I think you haven't escaped your quotes properly:

Edit: I think another quote was missing. Try this:

```
<Div class="panel-<%=i >= 100 ? \"Red\" : c >= 1 ? \"Blue\" : \"green\"%>" onclick="window.location = 'xxx.aspx'">
```